# Google Play - lost support for languages

Tags: android, google-play, android-location

My android app was using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0' library. 
During upload apk to Google Play I have information: 
"Locations: default + 55 languages".

Here are the gradle file dependencies, which makes me full support for the all locations:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

After removal of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0 library from my project I have information:
"Locations: default + 3 languages". (I have default and 3 more values directories).

Here are dependencies which cuts support only to few locations:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Why that's happen? I would like to have availability of app in all locations with fallback to default lang. But in new setup it looks like my app will be available only with listed locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `AppCompat` has localization for 55 languages for its own resources (for strings inside `AppCompat` library). With or without it your application has translations for just 3 languages. Shortly speaking your didn't loose any translations of your app by removing dependency on `AppCompat`.

Comment: Does it mean my application will be available for all locations with fallback to default language? Is it right.
I don't want to lost availability of my app in all locations.

Comment: Yes. If a localization for the device language is not found, then Android fallbacks to default translations located in `values/string.xml`